# Code style in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm writting some code in Angular + Django and I know that this code is ugly but I don't have any idea how can I refactoring it. Maybe you guys can help?

So, let's look at code, simplified code.

First of all, I have the models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUSES.items(), default='new')

class Ad(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="ad")
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, blank=True)

class AdStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad)
```

Okay, next I have simple serializers classes

```
class AdSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ad
        fields = ["url", "id", "image", "width", "height". "product"]
#etc...
```

And every model has his own factory in Angular

```
  .factory('AdStatus',["$resource", function ($resource){
    var Resource = $resource(
        "/api/ad_status/:ad_id/",
        {ad_id: '@id'},
        {
            query: {
                isArray: true,
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    var items = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return items.results;
                }
            },
            update: {
                method: "PUT",
            }
        },
        {
            stripTrailingSlashes: false
        }
    );
    Resource.prototype.changeStatus = function(status){
        this.status = status;
        this.$update();
    };
    return Resource;
  }])
/etc
```

And this in main code

```
//controller isn't bad

angular.module('controllers.statuses', [])
.controller('StatusCtr', ["$scope", "$stateParams", "StatusSetter",  function($scope, $stateParams, StatusSetter) {
    $scope.click = function(){
        $scope.t = StatusSetter.change($stateParams.id);// this is id of product
    };
}]);
```

But this, makes my a little... sick

```
.factory('StatusSetter', ["AdStatus", "Product", "Ad", function(AdStatus, Product, Ad){
    var changeStatus = function(id, productStatus, adStatus){
        var product = Product.get({product_id: id});
        product.$promise.then(function(data) {
            product.changeStatus(productStatus);
            var ads = Ad.query();
            var ad_status = AdStatus.query();
            var tmp = [];
            ads.$promise.then(function(data){
                for (var i = 0; i < ads.length; i++) {
                    if (ads[i].product == product.url){
                        tmp.push(ads[i]);
                    }
                }
                ad_status.$promise.then(function(data){
                    for (var i = 0; i < ad_status.length; i++){
                        for (var j = 0; j < tmp.length; j++){
                            if (ad_status[i].ad == tmp[j].url){
                                ad_status[i].changeStatus(adStatus);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                })
            });
        });
        return product;
    };
    return {
        change: function(id){
            return changeStatus(id, "new_status", 30);
        }
    }
  }])
```

The main philosophy of this code is: 
change AdStatuses which pointing at Ads (which pointing at Products)

Any ideas? maybe I can separate this 'filtering' to $resource or something.

Comment: there is a whole stackexchange site dedicated to code reviews

Comment: @redFive is correct, this would be a better fit on [codereview.se] - note that you don't need to "simplify" the code you post there, in fact it's actually better to include all of it; reviewers like to see your code in its full context and glory! :-) (just make sure you have a title that says *what the code is doing*, rather than *what you would like to get out of a peer review*)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as written before, it belongs to CodeReviews

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly where your are coming from. I have 10+ years of c++ coding behind me and started with javascript about a year ago. I'm afraid that you will have to get use to the JS way of writing code which is very different than what you are use to. 
Also you'll have to get used to the async processing.

Looking at you code, it seems that you should move these operations to your backend. If I read you code correctly, you retrieve our Product:

```
   var changeStatus = function(id, productStatus, adStatus){
   var product = Product.get({product_id: id});
   product.$promise.then(function(data) {
        product.changeStatus(productStatus);
```

and you instantly send a call to you backend to update the status. 
Why don't you move all this and the updating of the Ads status to your backend and integrate it into the processing of your get request?

This will save you  many calls to the backend as each changeStatus(); call is a REST call thus reducing load on the server + you simplify your JS code.

Comment: also keep in mind that if you at some point either ads or ad_status gets updated, you will have to rerun the code. Keeping the angularjs code in sync with your Django DB is not trivial so you should think about how to address this issue. The current code would not be able to detect changes in the DB.